# Properly closing or self-closing tags in HTML5

Tags: html, doctype

I have a question relating to closing HTML tags that are **self-closing**.

Which is more proper?

```
1. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
2. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
3. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also, if anyone has a good alternative for this `<meta>` tag, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
OR
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) article helped me some-what.

I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for my doc type.

Answer (score 5):

That entirely depends on your DOCTYPE: Self-closing tags are needed for compliance with the XHTML Standard. HTML4 and HTML5 don't require self-closing tags.

Comment: I use `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so I don't need to?

Comment: That means you're using HTML5, therefore you don't need self-closing tags.

Comment: HTML5 - FROM W3C:

Void elements: area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

"Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements

Answer (score 5):

In `HTML5` it is not strictly necessary to close *certain* HTML tags... (but some does)

Form [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#self-closing-start-tag-state):

> **8.1.2.1 Start tags**
>   ...
>   ...
>   6) Then, if the element is one of the [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), or if the element is a [foreign element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements), then there may be a single "/" (U+002F) character. This character has no effect on [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), but on [foreign element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements) it marks the start tag as **self-closing**.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it's personal preference to an extent, since it all returns the same result [in HTML 4/5]. However, I've seen #3 most commonly, and so that's just the way I've become accustomed to.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<img src="http://images.wisegeek.com/young-calico-cat.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" />
```

Comment: W3C HTML5 markup validator would probably freak out over this though.