# Should you, or should you NOT, close void elements/self-closing tags with a forward slash?

Tags: html, tags, xhtml

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I have looked at all of the directly relevant questions and answers, and as well as the indirect ones, regarding this topic. And thus far, as far as I can tell, they have not answered the question specifically how I have asked it. Though this is a very fine line here and this question will likely get posted as a duplicate but regardless If I could get the proper answer from any of you I would be immensely grateful.

As of this moment any website that I develop is should I, or should I not, close my void elemnts/self-closing tags. Is this possibly a best practice? E.g:

```
<br>
<br />
<img>
<img />
<hr>
<hr />
<meta>
<meta />
```

Here are some other questions that were asked and are similar. Remember. SHOULD I DO THIS? This is what I need to know. Thanks.

[Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

[Properly closing or self-closing tags in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687721/properly-closing-or-self-closing-tags-in-html5)

[Self-closing tags (void elements) in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693939/self-closing-tags-void-elements-in-html5)

[Properly closing or self-closing tags in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687721/properly-closing-or-self-closing-tags-in-html5)

My main concern is that by closing these tags like so `<br />` that it may make the tag incompatible with certain browsers or platforms. Is this true?

Anyway, as always thank you for your time and your replies. Have a great day and veterans day weekend.

Comment: "My main concern is that by closing these tags like so
that it may make the tag incompatible with certain browsers or platforms. Is this true?" Incredibly unlikely. Both with and without the slash are very common on the web, even within the same file, so any tool that favoured one or the other would not work properly with a large proportion of the web's documents.

Comment: ...except when web pages are served with an XML content type such as `application/xhtml+xml`, when you *must* include the slash. But few web sites do that.

Comment: [Link to my blog](https://mrlistersir.wordpress.com/2015/06/). tl;dr: it doesn't matter. I can post this as an answer if you like, but I'm not any kind of authority.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the comment. May I suggest to you a recommendation. That you perform a little bit of SEO on your websiteYour articles past and future. Your writing is good. Yoru answers are great. I know you get visitors already by looking at the public metrics to your site but that could be increased dramatically with some good SEO. It won't be much but depending on traffic you could even pull in a passive $100-$300 a month. Anyway, thanks and good luck!

Comment: @DeveloperDan Pfff, I'm not a regular blogger; sometimes, whole years go by without an article! So I wouldn't draw a crowd of regulars anyway. But thanks for the support!

Comment: @MrLister Np!, I wish you the best and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to conventions:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#notes,-tips-and-warnings

```
6.1.2.2 Void Elements
```

You should not use slash at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and answer. 6.1.2.2 - Void Elements, it says:  "In XHTML examples, due to the XML Well-Formedness requirements, void elements are always marked up using the trailing slash. XHTML Example: <img src="image.png" alt="example"/>" #*********#   "In HTML, however, the trailing slash is optional and, unless explicitly stated otherwise, is always omitted. HTML Example: <img src="image.png" alt="example">" It ALSO says that:  "In HTML, however, the trailing slash is optional". NOT that is should not be used. I'm so lost. Should I use it or should I not in an HTML website.

Comment: But the next lines says unless explicitly stated otherwise should be omitted. It means you should not use a slash in most tags there may be some tags with slash required but I do not know any.

Comment: That's actually just one guy's opinion, (Lachlan Hunt's) in a seven year old draft document.

Comment: You are right this document is no relevant sorry I found this thing https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags 8.1.2.1 6 Where it says it has no affect on void elements it has only effect on foreign elements I found also w3school reference https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp which says In HTML5, it is optional to close empty elements. Allowed: <meta charset="utf-8"> Also Allowed: <meta charset="utf-8" /> However, the closing slash (/) is REQUIRED in XHTML and XML. If you expect XML software to access your page, it is a good idea to keep the closing slash!

Comment: @Alohci Hey. Thanks for your reply also. I was pretty sure this was not THE authority but was not sure if it was an opinion either, So If I just want to use it as I always have and want to keep to be consistent will it hurt me in any way?